# Check the Sender of a Segue

Tags: ios, segue

In `-prepareForSegue:sender:`, how do I check if the `sender` was the view controller in which the `-prepareForSegue:sender:` is written?

In other words, how do I compare the `sender` argument to see what was passed when calling `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`

I tried:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"identifier"]) 
        if ([(MyViewControllerClass *)sender isEqual:self]) {
            // stuff
        } else {...}
    }
}
```

Also tried `==` in place of `isEqual:`.

The `else` part is always executed.

Comment: It depends what you want to check. Do you want to check a class or protocol? You also check against `self` - then you have to check for reference equality which would be === not ==

Comment: And don't forget that a segue has a source and destination, so there should be no need to check if a segue was sent from a sender - although there might be such a case and i can not see it.

Comment: I want to check whether the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` was called from the current controller or some other controller, where the value passed for `sender` is always `self` from the controllers.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out who the sender was so that I can set different values in the destination controller

Comment: @Mahesh Agrawal 's solution will work if you do not habe multiple potential MyViewControllerClass instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
if([sender isKindOfClass:[MyViewControllerClass class]){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: This didn't work as well. Still falls off to the `else` part.

Answer (score 1):

Update: First below code was crap ofcourse, here the version that *does* make sense:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:self];
}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if (segue.sourceViewController == sender) {
        NSLog(@"i have been the sender");
    }
}
```

**Stupid last version as reference what you should not do - answer to fast:**
I think you don`t want to check the sender. The sender could also be a Button activating the segue - i *guess* that you want to check against the sourceViewController.

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if (segue.sourceViewController == self) {
        NSLog(@"i have been the source");
    }
}
```

This will check if the segue will transition *from* the current ViewController.

Comment: Yup, makes sense now. Thanks.